# Get Yaw, Pitch, Roll from rotation vector

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am using `solvePnP` available in [OpenCV.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mjyc/opencv.js). Using this, I am able to get the rotation vector `rvec`.

How do I go about converting `rvec` to `yaw, pitch and roll` ? All examples point to creating a rotation matrix using `Rodrigues()` and then calling `decomposeProjectionMatrix`. But `OpenCV.js` does not come with those two methods.

Using plain javascript, how do I convert rotation vector `rvec` to `yaw pitch and roll` ?

I tried converting to Euler angles using this conversion [formula](http://euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/angleToEuler/index.htm). But the values are way off.

Any pointers is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice that I have a personal method, but I couldn't find `Rodrigues()` in the documentation, though...

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues